# Laravel Eager Loading: Sort using relationship column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `posts` and `authors` the two tables have a **One to Many Relationship**

```
posts table
id    title    author_id
1     Post 1   1
2     Post 2   2
3     Post 3   1

authors table
id    name
1     A
2     B
```

I would like to select all posts but sort by the author's name, **Is the following output achievable using Laravel's Eager Loading**

```
[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Post 1",
  "author_id": 1,
    "author": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A"
    }
  },
  {
  "id": 3,
  "title": "Post 3",
  "author_id": 1,
    "author": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A"
    }
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Post 2",
  "author_id": 2,
    "author": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "B"
    }
  }
]
```

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
Post::with(['author' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}])->get();
```

Comment: if you route model bind and $post is an instance of the Post model you can do: $post->load(['author' => function($name) { $name->sortBy('name', 'asc'}]);

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to order a small amount of element, you could go and order the resulting [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections) with its [SortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby) function:

```
$posts = Post::with('author')
         ->get()
         ->sortBy(function ($post) {
             return $post->author->name;
         });
```

Now, this isn't gonna work as expected when paginating the results.

For those cases I'd go to do it the other way around: first order the authors and then access their posts:

```
$authors = Author::with('posts')->orderBy('name')->get();

$posts = $authors->map(function ($author) {
    return $author->posts;
});
```